# Points and which LMVT is not true

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

Let $f(x)=x^3 +3x + 2$ and $ x=c $ be a point such that $ f'(c) ≠ (f(b) - f(a))/(b-a)$  for any two values of  $a,b \in \mathbb{R} $

How to find such points?

I tried to solve it geometrically, I drew graph of the function and noted that slope of the tangent at inflexion point i.e. $ x=0 $ is such that it does not satisfy above condition or no chord of the graph of this function is parallel to tangent at this point.

In my textbook the answer was

"For such points $f''(x)=0$ "

For every inflection point is this true?

Please Explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g_c(x) = f(x) - f'(c)x$. We have $g(b) - g(a) = f(b) - f(a) - f'(c)(b-a)$, so if $g(a) = g(b)$, then $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$. So you could be looking for points where $g_c$ is injective (which is stronger than the assumptions of $LM. One criterium to detect injectivity is if the function is strictly increasing.

In the case of $f(x)$, we have $g_c'(x) = f'(x) - f'(c) = 3(x^2+1) - 3(c^2+1) = 3(x^2-c^2)$. If $c=0$, the derivative of $g_c$ is always non-negative (and only zero at one point, namely $0$), so $g_c$ is strictly increasing, hence injective.

If $c \neq 0$, then the derivative is zero at two distinct points, and studying the sign of the derivative shows that $g_c$ admits a local maximum followed by a local minimum. Using the intermediate value theorem on $g_c$ (not on $f$), you can show that there are points $a < b$ with $g_c(a) = g_c(b)$. (For instance, pick $b$ as the local minimum, and use the intermediate value theorem to show that $g_c$ takes the local minimum as a value $a$ somewhere between the local maximum and $-\infty$).

Hope that helps,